Using SSH reverse tunnel in combination with DNAT
I use a jumphost to make my local running servers available from the internet. I dont want every machine to use its own tunnel anymore, so I'd like to use one machine to manage this.
It's a normal debian system which connects to the jumphost an routes the traffic to the servers.
The routing/DNAT itself is working fine when I try it from my internal network. When I try to connect to the debian system, I reach the server.
But from outside via the jumphost it doesnt work since the last reboot. The tunnel ist working, but somehow tha traffic arriving through the tunnel is not NATet anymore.
This is how the start up script looks like:
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.5:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.10.10.5:443
autossh -M 9998 -f -p PORT -N -R 443:localhost:443 root@JUMPHOST
autossh -M 9999 -f -p PORT -N -R 80:localhost:80 root@JUMPHOST

I'd be very thankful for any advice.
Best Regards
Roman

Were there any recent upgrades (e.g. before last reboot)? What is in ssh logs? Are sshd processes really listening on ports 443 and 80? Notice, by the way, that you can run several tunnels in a single SSH session, but that would be prone to chocking each other. In any case, I can suggest that as a temporary solution (when moving the service from one server to another), but not as permanent solution, so I am tempting to close this as not reasonable way to solve business IT problems.

Thanks for your answer! On the jumphost sshd is listening on ports 443 and 80. I can reach the local debian system from outside, but the routing to the actual webserver does not work. The routing itself is working for internal connections.
I changed nothing on the debian system. I installed it, installed iptables, created the connection etc., everything worked. After the first reboot, it didn't

On which interface will the connection through the ssh tunnel come in?

sshd "is listening" ­— show us ss -lnpt | grep sshd (on the remote). Maybe it's listening on localhost? It's the default setting of OpenSSH that you can't set up reverse tunnels listening on non-localhost address unless you explicitly permitted that in the sshd_config.
